# Creating Branch.io dynamic URLs to pass and fetch params in deep linking

Tags: android, ios, deep-linking, branch.io

I am able to redirect the user to the webpage(www.example.com) if app is not installed using Branch.io dashboard settings. But in my case, the URL I write in URL scheme or fallback, needs to be dynamic and will have some info of the user, which page to open in the app etc. as parameters. I am able to create a link with parameters in dashboard but how do I retrieve those params in my app ?

Answer (score 0):

Branch's SDK is required to be integrated in your app. The callback you see [here](https://dev.branch.io/recipes/quickstart_guide/ios/#initialize-sdk-and-register-deep-link-routing-function) (pending you've set everything else up correctly) is going to deliver those parameters you've added to the link you created.

For iOS, you'd like do the following:

```
Branch *branch = [Branch getInstance];
[branch initSessionWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions andRegisterDeepLinkHandler:^(NSDictionary *params, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
        NSLog(@"params: %@", params.description);
    }
}];
```

The 'params' variable above would contain those parameters.